# Hibernate optimistic concurrency control with @version annotation

Tags: hibernate

I am relatively new to Hibernate. I am trying to use optimistic concurrency by annotating a timestamp field

```
@Entity
public class Request implements java.io.Serializable {
```

....

```
@Version
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP", length = 26)
public Date getLastUpdateTimestamp() {
    return this.lastUpdateTimestamp;
}
```

then I expect the update code below to throw StaleObjectStateException() when concurrent transactions update my entity

```
request.setStatus(status);
request.setLastUpdateTimestamp(currenttimestamp);
s.save(request);
```

I run the code in debugger and pause to ensure that one thread executes this code first and then resume the other thread. I can see the resulting SQL and it has

```
update REQUEST ... where ID=? and LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP=?
```

so my understanding the update shoudld fail and StaleObjectStateException() should be thrown, but it does not happen. What am I missing?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: hey did u got any answer related ? i am also desperately searching for it